# Check if termset exists in termstore using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm attempting to create a script that creates the term group, set and name in that order.

```
$TermGroup = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Term  group'
$TermSet = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Term  set'
$TermName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Term  name'

#Check if Term Group is empty
If($TermGroup)
{
#Check if Term group exists
If(-Not(Get-PnPTermGroup -Identity $TermGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
    #Create new group in Termstore
    New-PnPTermGroup -Name $TermGroup -Description $TermGroupDescription
    Write-host -f Green "Term Group '$TermGroup' created successfully!"
}
Else
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Term Group '$TermGroup' already exists!"
}
}
Else
{
   Write-host -f Yellow "No 'TermGroup' provided"
}

#Check if Term Set is empty
If($TermSet)
{
#Check if Term set exists
If(-Not(Get-PnPTermSet -Identity $TermSet -TermGroup $TermGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
    #Create new set in Termstore
    New-PnPTermSet -Name $TermSet -TermGroup $TermGroup
    Write-host -f Green "Term Set '$TermSet' created successfully!"
}
Else
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Term Set '$TermSet' already exists!"
}
}
Else
{
   Write-host -f Yellow "No 'TermSet' provided"
}

#Check if Term Name is empty
If($TermName)
{
#Check is Term Name exists
If(-Not(Get-PnPTerm -Identity $TermName -TermSet $TermSet -TermGroup $TermGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
    #Create new Term
    New-PnPTerm -Name $TermName -TermSet $TermSet -TermGroup $TermGroup
}
Else
{
    Write-host -f Yellow "Term 'TermName' already exists!"
}
}
Else
{
   Write-host -f Yellow "No 'TermName' provided"
}
```

but keep getting this error for both the term set and name portion.

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: lcid

Can anyone assist why this may be?

Comment: Which command is throwing the error? (set `$ErrorView = 'NormalView'` or `$ErrorView = 'DetailedView'` if PowerShell isn't showing error context)

Comment: ```
  New-PnPTermSet -Name $TermSet -TermGroup $TermGroup
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: lcid

```
Is what im seeing

Comment: Perhaps you need to create the term group first?

Comment: I did. I pasted the full script i'm attempting to create above. Its supposed to create the term group, set, and name in that order and check for existing before doing so.

Comment: Im getting the issue with just ``` New-PnPTermSet -Name "testTermSet" -TermGroup "testTermGroupName"``` so maybe somethings off with my command

Answer (score 0):

added -Lcid "1033" and it worked.